# Should I put "it" before "is" to make the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: pronouns, clauses

As I am preparing for my upcoming writing exam, I came across this sentence as a so-called model essay. However, when reading it, I think I need to put "it" in front of "is" since it is another clause.

> However, coal overtook natural gas in 1990 and despite some fluctuation, is set to be the second most used fuel in 2030 with just over 30q.
>
> However, coal overtook natural gas in 1990 and despite some fluctuation, **it** is set to be the second most used fuel in 2030 with just over 30q.

Comment: Not necessarily. "Coal" is used as a shared subject for both phrases

Comment: I believe the confusion over pronouns and antecedents is stemming from a missing comma to offset the interruption in the sentence. So much for the essay being a “model.” The grammatically correct sentence is “However, coal overtook natural gas in 1990 and, despite some fluctuation, is set to be the second most used fuel in 2030 with just over 30q.”